# How do I get a list of roles for the currently logged in user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to know what roles a logged in user belongs to without having to check the user against all possible roles (i.e. using Page.User.IsInRole())

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[`using System.Web.Security;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.aspx)

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser()
```

Or

`Roles.GetRolesForUser(String)` if not targeting the currently logged in user.

Comment: what about when the Role Manager feature has not been enabled?

Comment: If the Role Manager feature has not been enabled, enable it in Web.config: `<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />`

Answer (score 1):

try this if you want to check the currently logged in user for specific role:

```
Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")
```

Comment: Didn't the question specifically ask for a way to avoid checking each role individually?

Comment: Add some useful reference if you can,To explain some need information.